# Error with classes having objects as attributes c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Hello guys i got a error when im doing this in c++.

```
class Position {
private:
    int posX;
    int posY;
public:
    Position(int posX, int posY) {
        this->posX = posX;
        this->posY = posY;
    }

    int getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }
    int getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }
};

class SpaceShip {
private:
    Position position;
public: 
    SpaceShip(Position position) {
         this->position = position;
    }
};

int main() {

    Position position(10, 10);
    SpaceShip spaceShip(position);
    return 0;
}
```

and the error i got is this.

Doesn't exist any default constructor for the clase "Position"

What i could do to solve the problem?
And also, What is the correct form to create a object attribute for a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"What i could do to solve the problem?"*

You can declare/define some default constructor in your class (exactly what the error message tells you):

```
 Position() : posX(0), posY(0) {
 }
```

Also you should provide an appropriate copy constructor, and assignment operator:

```
 Position(const Position& rhs) : posX(rhs.posX), posY(rhs.posY) {
 }

 Position& operator=(const Position& rhs) {
      posX = rhs.posX;
      posY = rhs.posY;
      return *this;
 }
```

Have a look at [What is The Rule of 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) please.

For something common like a `Position` class it's at least good style to do so, and may come handy in many other situations.

---

*"And also, What is the correct form to create a object attribute for a class?"*

As stated in the other answer the correct form is to use the member initializer list in the constructor of the `SpaceShip` class:

```
   SpaceShip(Position position)
   : position(position) { }
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note:
The *default constructor*, *copy constructor* and *assignment operator* are supplied by the compiler automatically, unless you declare any specialized constructor.

Comment: Yeah, but in other languages like java i can declare a object but no initialize it. can i do it in c++? or have i by obligation create a default constructor ?

Comment: @ErickJimenez C++ isn't java, forget about what you think you know.

Comment: The rule of 3 says that *if* you need a user defined (1) copy constructor or (2) assignment operator or (3) destructor, then you probably need all 3. This class needs none of them.

Comment: I think that is strange, use a default constructor just for declare a empty or null variable, i used before, but i found strange, but ok, thanks :)

Comment: @ErickJimenez: If you don't think your class should have a default constructor, then don't give it one. See the other answer, that will solve your problem without adding any extra unwanted constructors.

Comment: @ErickJimenez There's nothing like _"empty or null variable"_ in c++ actually. You may use pointers, but that's probably not a good idea, and a completely different kettle of fish.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'd suppose for something like `Position` it would be a good idea, making it a _nice class_ in the long term.

Comment: Maybe so, that's a judgement call. But, generally speaking, the correct way to solve this problem is with a member initialization list, not adding a default constructor just to shut the compiler up. There are some classes where default construction is just not appropriate.

Comment: @ErickJimenez You might consider accepting the other answer, still mine provides some useful considerations IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

Construction of data members and base classes is done using the *member initializer-list*. If a data member of class type or a base class hasn't been initialized using the initializer-list, then it is default-constructed instead. Since your class doesn't have a default-constructor, you get the error.

Inside the constructor, `this->position = position` is an *assignment*, not a constructor call. `position` was default-constructed before you got to this line. You need to replace it with this:

```
SpaceShip(Position position)
    : position(position)
{ }
```

This uses the member initializer-list to call the copy-constructor `Position::Position(Position const&)`.

Comment: Or, does the OP need a default constructor for `Position`: `Position(int new_x = 0, int new_y = 0) : x(new_x), y(new_y) { ; }`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'd suppose the OP needs both, while this solves the 1st stage problem.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think I was wrong, it was actually my answer solving the 1st stage problem, while this one solves the real issue about initializing the `position` member.